# iPhone EXC_BAD_ACCESS after the viewDidAppear event

Tags: iphone, ios4, exc-bad-access

I need an hint on where to search for detecting what causes a Crash with message EXC_BAD_ACCESS, which it should be related to "retain - release" questions. It happens in a moment AFTER the event viewDidAppear.

```
0   0x01285a63 in objc_msgSend  
1   0x0580e400 in ??  
2   0x0105fb8d in _ CFAutoreleasePoolPop  
3   0x00022443 in -[NSAutoreleasePool release]  
4   0x002d3bf2 in _ UIApplicationHandleEvent  
5   0x018cca36 in PurpleEventCallback  
6   0x01105064 in __ CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__  
7   0x010656f7 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1  
8   0x01062983 in __CFRunLoopRun  
9   0x01062240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific  
10  0x01062161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode  
11  0x002cafa8 in -[UIApplication _run]  
12  0x002d742e in UIApplicationMain  
13  0x00001ca0 in main at main.m:14
```

The strange thing is that it ***doesn't*** happen ***always***, just sometimes; I've checked the whole class that is first launched, but I can't see anything that may cause this trouble. In addition to that, if I dig step by step with the debugger, it seems that the problem never occurs, maybe a simulator problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the autorelease pool is trying to release an object that is already deallocated. I guess NSZombie would help finding the object in question.

**EDIT:** To activate NSZombie do the following:

1. Get info of the executable.
2. Go to the arguments tab.
3. In the "Variables to be set in the environment:" section add:

Name: NSZombieEnabled
Value: YES

Then run your app as usual and when it crashes it should tell you which deallocated object received the release message.

Comment: The message was not so detailed, but it did the job, I managed to find out the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but a tip - compile the app for the simulator, launch the Instruments and add memory allocation tool with "NSZombies enabled" from library.  Run the app in instruments until you get a notice about sent message to zombie object.

Comment: Thank you, the Zombie did the job :)